# How would I use AngularJS promises to ensure that fetched data updates the scope?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am working on separating some JSON requests out of a controller and into a factory service in angular and sort of have it working. Presently, when I update the data (as with a request for new data) I have to make the request twice to actually see the updated data. I presume, from my presently limited knowledge of Angular that I am missing the promise aspect. However, I am not really sure how best to proceed. Code follows:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('weatherApp', [])
    
    .controller('MyWeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'weather', function($scope, $http, $log, weather) {
      $scope.city = 'Cincinnati';
      $scope.units = 'imperial';

      $scope.updateData = function() {
        weather.updateData($scope, $http, $log);
      };

      // Initial run to fetch weather data
      $scope.updateData();
    }])


    // Set up a service factory to fetch current and forecast data
    .factory('weather', ['$http', function($http) {
      var services = {};

      services.updateData = function(scope, http, log) {
        this.updateCurrent(scope, http, log);
      }

      // Get current data
      services.updateCurrent = function(scope, http, log) {
        // Fetch current weather data from api
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

        http.jsonp(url, {params: {
          q: scope.city,
          units: scope.units,
          callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          scope.main = data.main;
          scope.wind = data.wind;
          scope.description = data.weather[0].description;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          log.error('Could not retrieve data from '+url);
        });
      };

      return services;
    }]);

} (window.angular));
```

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}    

h2 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Weather checker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="weatherApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyWeatherController">

        <h2>Current weather in {{city}}</h2>
        <div class="section current">
          <form name="weather-form">
            <label for="city">City, State / Zip code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              ng-model="city" 
              ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
            <br>
            <label for="units">Units</label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="metric"> Metric
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="imperial"> Imperial<br>
            <button ng-click="updateData()">Update</button>
            <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <p>Temperature: {{main.temp}}</p>
            <p>Wind speed: {{wind.speed}}</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can tell if you run this, you have to update twice to get the new data to display in the view. Any suggestions on some examples or feedback on next steps would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Testing your code it works. Perhaps you're not waiting for the ajax call to load. If you do a `console.log` before you make the ajax call and another when you receive the results you'll see that it is working, it just takes some time for the data to come back from the server. Also take a look at @pankajparkar's answer as it shows how to more cleanly separate your code so that you don't have to pass the scope around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `ng-model-options` directive.

City value is not updated in the model till we submit the form.

So, when after changing the city, when we click for the first time, the values are fetched for the old city, which will not reflect any changes in the UI. As this is a submit action this will update the model.

When we click second time, values are fetched with the new city value.

Comment: Good call. However, I really dont want the {{city}} to update until the new data is on it's way. From a UX standpoint it would be "weird".

Comment: for the input use `ng-model=city`, in the markup use `{{currentCity}}`, after fetching the response update the currentCity with city.

Comment: it is not affecting while making ajax..value is passed correctly the updated one

Comment: Great idea about the {{currentCity}} that does the trick! Now I will have to try something else to work with $resource or $q :-) Marking this as correct.

Comment: @pankajparkar, your fiddle is using angular 1.2. try with angular 1.3. ng-model-options are introduced in 1.3

Answer (score 1):

Here is implementation with promise.

Your code with promise would look like this, you shouldn't pass variable like $scope, $http, $log to service they will be easily available inside service by injecting it dependency.

`scope` variables should not get modified using service, you should return a promise from service and inside the promise success or error you can do modify your scope.

From service I returned `$http.jsonp` which already has promise so you don't need to care about returning promise, and that promise get resolved inside `.success` function and you can get reject promise inside `.error` function

**CODE**

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = angular.module('weatherApp', [])

        .controller('MyWeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'weather', function ($scope, $http, $log, weather) {
        $scope.city = 'Cincinnati';
        $scope.units = 'imperial';

        $scope.updateData = function () {
            weather.updateData($scope.city, $scope.units).
            then(function (res) {
                var data = res.data;
                $scope.main = data.main;
                $scope.wind = data.wind;
                $scope.description = data.weather[0].description;
            },function (data) {
                $log.error('Could not retrieve data from ' + url);
            })

        };

        // Initial run to fetch weather data
        $scope.updateData();
    }])


    // Set up a service factory to fetch current and forecast data
    .factory('weather', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
        var services = {};

        services.updateData = function (city, units) {
            return this.updateCurrent(city, units);
        };

        // Get current data
        services.updateCurrent = function (city, units) {
            // Fetch current weather data from api
            var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

            return $http.jsonp(url, {
                params: {
                    q: city,
                    units: units,
                    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return data;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.error('Could not retrieve data from ' + url);
                return data;
            });

        };

        return services;
    }]);

}(window.angular));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBMDs/34/)

Hope this could helpful to you, Thanks.

Comment: I am hoping to keep the success and error out of the controller. Also, it appears that the city field's ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'} is ignored with this solution. Are you seeing that too? Sort of like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16944019/1857689

Comment: @DerekWebb Thats my bad, angular version is lower in my fiddle that why it is working properly, that why it was not affecting, i think my answer would help you with promise concept

Comment: True, and I do plan to tinker with it. Though, strangely enough I found that the promise was not the issue at all - It was an assumption on my part. I'm still very new to Angular...

Comment: I have heard that I should keep the scope and so forth out of my factory though so I will definitely swing back around to this. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @DerekWebb I already mentioned those things in answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('weatherApp', [])
    
    .controller('MyWeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'weather', function($scope, $http, $log, weather) {
      $scope.city = 'Cincinnati';
      $scope.units = 'imperial';

      $scope.updateData = function() {
        weather.updateData($scope, $http, $log);
      };

      // Initial run to fetch weather data
      $scope.updateData();
    }])


    // Set up a service factory to fetch current and forecast data
    .factory('weather', ['$http', function($http) {
      var services = {};

      services.updateData = function(scope, http, log) {
        this.updateCurrent(scope, http, log);
      }

      // Get current data
      services.updateCurrent = function(scope, http, log) {
        // Fetch current weather data from api
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

        http.jsonp(url, {params: {
          q: scope.city,
          units: scope.units,
          callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          scope.main = data.main;
          scope.wind = data.wind;
          scope.description = data.weather[0].description;
          $scope.digest();
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          log.error('Could not retrieve data from '+url);
        });
      };

      return services;
    }]);

} (window.angular));
```

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}    

h2 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0">
  <head>
    <title>Weather checker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="weatherApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyWeatherController">

        <h2>Current weather in {{city}}</h2>
        <div class="section current">
          <form name="weather-form">
            <label for="city">City, State / Zip code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              ng-model="city" 
              ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
            <br>
            <label for="units">Units</label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="metric"> Metric
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="imperial"> Imperial<br>
            <button ng-click="updateData()">Update</button>
            <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <p>Temperature: {{main.temp}}</p>
            <p>Wind speed: {{wind.speed}}</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have just added $scope.digest() in success to reflect changes at UI

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't do the trick... Still requires two clicks on update by my count. Pretty sure I need to refactor this to use $q promises or $resource but I am not quite sure how to best go about it yet. The examples I have seen show the service with no parameters. Mine has 3.

Comment: but code is working at this page you just need to wait for some moment since it is ajax.yes definitely you can use promise .promises and deferred is used to make a call sync

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways (well, probably many more) you could go here.
You could create a promise and return the data that comes back from the http call in the promise, to be resolved in the controller. Check out the 2nd code block on the documentation for $q [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to see how to do this.

I would suggest, however, that instead, in your service you create a public property to hold the data. You can then access it from your controller. Due to Angular's data binding, when the server response eventually comes back and the data gets stored in the service, the controller will automatically "see" the updated value.

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('weatherApp', [])
    
    .controller('MyWeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'weather', function($scope, $http, $log, weather) {
      //here you expose the service to your scope.  From here you can
      //get at all your data in the view by using weather.result
      $scope.weather = weather;
      
      $scope.city = 'Cincinnati';
      $scope.units = 'imperial';

      $scope.updateData = function() {
        weather.updateData($scope, $http, $log);
      };

      // Initial run to fetch weather data
      $scope.updateData();
    }])


    // Set up a service factory to fetch current and forecast data
    .factory('weather', ['$http', function($http) {
      var services = {};
      
      //make the server response data part of the service's public API
      services.details = {
          someDetail: "",
          someOtherThing: []
      }

      services.updateData = function(scope, http, log) {
        this.updateCurrent(scope, http, log);
      }

      // Get current data
      services.updateCurrent = function(scope, http, log) {
        // Fetch current weather data from api
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

        http.jsonp(url, {params: {
          q: scope.city,
          units: scope.units,
          callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          //here we assign the data to the service's result property.
          services.details.someDetail = data.someDetail;
          services.details.someOtherThing = data.someOtherThing;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          log.error('Could not retrieve data from '+url);
        });
      };

      return services;
    }]);

} (window.angular));
```

```html
<p>Some detail:{{weather.details.someDetail}}</p>
<p>Some other thing: {{weather.details.someOTherThing}}</p>
```

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't seem to result in a functional method though. I am thinking I would need to check $scope.weather.results somewhere to test if the data were present, and if so, update the view. Seems kind of roundabout to me but it may be worth playing with. Also, without declaring $scope.weather = {}; before $scope.weather.results = weather.results; Angular throws an error (TypeError: Cannot set property 'results' of undefined). But still, an interesting concept. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that was in error. I've updated the snippet to show a better example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}` from your html and it's working fine :)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myApp = angular.module('weatherApp', [])
    
    .controller('MyWeatherController', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'weather', function($scope, $http, $log, weather) {
      $scope.city = 'Cincinnati';
      $scope.units = 'imperial';

      $scope.updateData = function() {
        weather.updateData($scope, $http, $log);
      };

      // Initial run to fetch weather data
      $scope.updateData();
    }])


    // Set up a service factory to fetch current and forecast data
    .factory('weather', ['$http', function($http) {
      var services = {};

      services.updateData = function(scope, http, log) {
        this.updateCurrent(scope, http, log);
      }

      // Get current data
      services.updateCurrent = function(scope, http, log) {
        // Fetch current weather data from api
        var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';

        http.jsonp(url, {params: {
          q: scope.city,
          units: scope.units,
          callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
        }})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          scope.main = data.main;
          scope.wind = data.wind;
          scope.description = data.weather[0].description;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          log.error('Could not retrieve data from '+url);
        });
      };

      return services;
    }]);

} (window.angular));
```

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2em auto;
}    

h2 {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Weather checker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="weatherApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyWeatherController">

        <h2>Current weather in {{city}}</h2>
        <div class="section current">
          <form name="weather-form">
            <label for="city">City, State / Zip code</label>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              ng-model="city">
            <br>
            <label for="units">Units</label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="metric"> Metric
            <input type="radio" ng-model="units" value="imperial"> Imperial<br>
            <button ng-click="updateData()">Update</button>
            <h3>{{data.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <p>Temperature: {{main.temp}}</p>
            <p>Wind speed: {{wind.speed}}</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```