# $scope not able to get data from factory using $http.get in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, factory, httpservice

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.factory('factoryProvider', function ($http, $q) {
    var facObj = {};
    facObj.getLastWorkplace = $http.get('plugins/wcf-service/ServiceProvider.svc/getLastWorkPlacesJSON')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    return facObj;
});

app.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, factoryProvider) {

    factoryProvider.getLastWorkplace.then(function (successResponse) {
        $scope.wp = successResponse;
        console.log('inside');
        console.log($scope.wp); // Return an object that I want
    });
    console.log('outside');
    console.log($scope.wp); // $scope.wp is empty
});
```

The outside console log runs first, inside console log is the second. The problem is that $scope.wp can just get data in getLastWorkplace callback functions and it can not bind data to ng-model(using wp.property). How to solve it?
Thanks for your reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS factory http returns empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336987/angularjs-factory-http-returns-empty)

Comment: i think you should use a $promise to bind the object.

Comment: Ok, it works outside but $scope.wp is an $$state
:
Object. How can I access the data

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `$scope.wp` twice and the final assignment is the return value of your `getLastWorkplace` call (which you aren't returning anything.)

Change it to this...

```
factoryProvider.getLastWorkplace.then(function (successResponse) {
    $scope.wp = successResponse;
});
```

or...

```
$scope.wp = factoryProvider.getLastWorkplace;
```

but not both.

Comment: $scope.wp can recieve data that I want but It doesn still bind data to ng-model

Comment: Try assigning `$scope.wp = {}` before you call your provider. Your last `console.log` will still be empty though because it runs before your promise resolves. Also, if it's still not working then post your template.